# What do the settings on a multimeter mean?

Tags: resistance, multimeter, ohms, conductivity

I wanted to measure the resistance in ohms of an apple, so I plugged my digital multimeter into either end of the apple and adjusted the settings up to 200k and it gave me a reading of about 68. Because the meter was set to 200k does that mean I have to do 68 x 200000 to get the number of ohms for the apple or something else? Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Comment: What does your multimeter manual have to say? Usually the range given is the *maximum* value that can be measured.

Comment: @user2943160 it's long gone. Maybe it could be on the internet.

Comment: Generally on the 200k range the multi-meter can read up to a maximum of 199. So your reading of 68 means 68k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact the manual for your particular meter is missing, there are some fundamental concepts to using multimeters which you should familiarize yourself with.

I would recommend checking out some of the numerous online tutorials, such as [this one from LadyAda](https://learn.adafruit.com/multimeters/), about multimeter usage. ([Measuring resistance, specifically.](https://learn.adafruit.com/multimeters/resistance))

Alternatively, you may want to acquire or borrow a meter with a manual and read up on it.

Ranges on meters denote the *maximum* value that the range supports. So `200k` means you can measure from 0 to 200 kΩ. All of the readings shown while using that range should be in kΩ.

For example, if you instead set the range to 200 Ω, it would measure from 0 to 200 Ω, in which case the apple at 68kΩ would be *out of range*. The multimeter would display some sort of message to indicate out of range, but this differs by manufacturer/model.

Comment: Perfect. Explained everything perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: For a lot of multimeter, this denotes the maximum range for which the accuracy is guaranteed. They have some percent of over range that they still display, often 10 or 20%